# Unable to connect to Oracle instant client 19 with PHP

Tags: php, oracle, oci8

I am just trying to set up a Oracle instant client 19 database connection using PHP and XAMPP.

I have followed several Youtube videos, other stack posts and it still does not show the oci8 module on phpinfo.php. I also recieve the error `Call to undefined function oci_connect()`

What I have done:

- Installed XAMPP with PHP enabled.
- Downloaded Version 19.9.0.0.0 Basic x64 from - https://www.oracle.com/uk/database/technologies/instant-client/winx64-64-downloads.html and extracted to C:\ named instantclient_19_9
- Set up my environment path = C:\instantclient_19_9
- Restarted PC
- Downloaded oci.dll from - http://pecl.php.net/package/oci8/2.0.8/windows
- Selected 5.5 Safe thread x64
- Extracted into C:/xampp/php/ext
- Went into php.ini and removed semi-colon from extension=oci8_19
- Restarted Apache
- Looking in XAMPP/php/ext, there is php_oci8.dll and php_oci8_19.dll extensions there.
- Went onto phpinfo.php and nothing is displaying for oci8

Not sure what else I need to do, at this point, all walkthroughs show their phpinfo pages and they all show the oci extension. I tried uninstalling XAMPP and removing all files then trying again but each time it doesn't work so I must be missing something. I have done this for SQLITE and MYSQL and they worked just fine, just oracle.

For extra measures, I have also tried an answer someone suggested in a post and it also hasn't worked:

Add oci.dll, oraociei19.dll, and oraons.dll from C:\instantclient_19_9 to xampp/apache/bin folder. Replace the existing ones.

Restart the Apache

Comment: Is your apache and php also 64-bit?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I donwloaded the 64-bit version of XAMPP which I would assume comes with the 64-bit versions of apache and php

Comment: Why did you get such an old version of OCI8 - what version of PHP is in your XAMPP package? Did you follow https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/installing-xampp-for-php-and-oracle-database ? Even 3 years ago that post shows using a newer version of OCI8.  Also, did you install the required VS Redistributable as noted on the Instant Client download page?

Comment: @ChristopherJones I tried a bunch of different versions of OCI8, I downloaded 3.0.1 the first time and it didn't work, this was just the last one I tried. I have C++ 2013 Redistributable (both x64 and x86) and 2015-2019 (x64). I followed multiple other blogs but not the one mentioned however having a look they state that oci8 should come with the newest version of XAMPP and that is what I have done so why would I need to go and grab the oci8 .dlls myself? I will reset and try again with the blog you mentioned.

Comment: I'm not sure why you need(ed) to grab any other OCI8 DLL.  Our blog post has an "if", saying "Oracle OCI8 is pre-installed in XAMPP but if you need a newer version you can download an updated OCI8 PECL package".  So it is up to you to decide if you need a newer version.  Sometimes PECL releases occur in between PHP releases, so PECL can be a bit ahead.

Comment: @ChristopherJones I have got the group im working with to all try this blog that you have written and none of us have oci8 as part of the php even though we have followed everything you stated ignoring step 4, used instandclient12_2 but still nothing.